# UIWindow's rootViewController considerations

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, uiwindow, rootview

I've been reading several posts dealing with switching the `rootViewController` of the window, and sometimes it is said that keeping a same `rootViewController` throughout the app's lifecycle is better than switching it, and other posts are related to changing the `rootViewController` at some point of the app. I'm confused about this, and I couldn't find any recommendation regarding this point in Apple's docs.

What should be the best practice when you are likely to have different content view controllers in an app? For example, let's say you have a tabbed app (`UITabBarController`) that you want first to show a welcome view for signing in or signing up (`UINavigationController`):

1) Approach with a fixed `rootViewController`. I think you should set the `UITabBarController` as the `rootViewController`, as the core of the app is tabbed, but if user credentials are needed, then set a `UINavigationController` within the `UITabBarController`, hiding the tab bar, to push the welcome view and navigate to Sign In/Sign Up view controllers.

2) Approach switching `rootViewController`. Firstly, if user credentials needed, set the `UINavigationController` as the `rootViewController` to show the welcome view and navigate to Sign In/Sign Up, and, once user credentials successfully provided or account successfully created, switch the `rootViewController` to the `UITabBarController` to show the core tabbed app.

In case the best general approach is switching `rootViewController` as needed, what are the memory management considerations you'd take into account? Should I need to have two `strong` properties in AppDelegate (`UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`)? And what about the transition between the view controllers when switching the `rootViewController`: will it be smooth, or should you animate it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may get closed since your question is basically asking people's opinions. I'd opt for option 1. Present the login screen as a modal view controller over the root controller anytime you need the user to login. Dismiss it when they login successfully. No need to switch root controllers.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. I think presenting the login view in top of the root will be the best way if only having a login view, but in this scenario, I don´t have an only view for signing in, I have a welcome view with two buttons and a welcome view -> sign in / sign up view navigation hierarchy, so should presenting modally such hierarchy be the best way as well?

Comment: @rmaddy any further thought's addressing AppsDev's comment? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The approach  of switching rootViewController suits good  . Firstly, if user credentials needed, set the `UINavigationController` as the rootViewController to show the welcome view and navigate to Sign In/Sign Up, and, once user credentials successfully provided or account successfully created, switch the rootViewController to the `UITabBarController` to show the core tabbed app

If you would like to store User credentials inside tabbarcontroller . Store them in `NSUserDefaults` or into `plist` in your main bundle or created in document directory .